# How to read data line by line from String buffer and match with another String

Tags: java

I write the code

```
public class keys {

    private static final String[] keyss = {
        "HGDLV-KLLQC-DM3ON-MAUOX-FNQK5",
        "HQKLD-NYRDL-NJXCV-BVCKF-NRKLC", 
        "LDFCV-BDJCQ-VMFQV-FNRKC-NFCFL"
         //and many more
    };

    public static String getKey(String key) {
        boolean b = Arrays.asList(keyss).contains(key);
        if (b == true) {
            key = "approved";
        } else {
            key = "unapproved";
        }
        return key;
    }
```

and gets the approved for all Strings even if the above dosen't match with the user specified string

Comment: First of all, all class name **must** start with an upper case letter. Also, what value does the user pass as `key` parameter?

Comment: What exactly is your question? That code seems to work as I would expect..

Comment: Apart from being a poor design, it does actually work. There is no real problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare Strings using equals. Also the implementation of getKeys() is too complicated and redundant.. Consider changing it to:

```
public class Keys {
    private static final String[] keys = {
        "HGDLV-KLLQC-DM3ON-MAUOX-FNQK5",
        "HQKLD-NYRDL-NJXCV-BVCKF-NRKLC", 
        "LDFCV-BDJCQ-VMFQV-FNRKC-NFCFL"
         //and many more
    };

    public static String getKey(String key) {
        for(String current : keys){
            if(current.equals(key)){
                return "approved";
            }
        }
        return "unapproved";
    }
}
```

No need to use `Arrays` in the way you use it, nor a `boolean` switch..

You might want to check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus) to read about comparing Strings.

Comment: Sorry, but there is problem in the method in main program not in class. I checked it more time and found no problem in class code. I appreciate for the optimized code.